# Can ORMs represent every possible SQL query?

Tags: orm, theory

I'm currently trying to figure out how powerful ORMs are. I've written pretty simple web applications where you just needed simple CRUD queries and was super happy with the ORM I was using. But for complex analytical queries I didn't even attempt to use the ORM. It might very well be that in the specific cases it was just my limited knowledge. But on a more general note, are there any statements about any ORM that they can / cannot represent any possible SQL query? How powerful are ORMs?

(I'm most familiar with SQLAlchemy of Python)

Please note:

- Yes, many ORMs support sending raw SQL. I don't consider that part of the ORM, though. My question is specifically about the ORM part only.

Answer (score 0):

It's subtle. The point of an ORM is to map object to relational constructs. The ORMs I've used (mostly based on the ActiveRecord pattern) do a really good job of mapping basic SQL constructs into the object-oriented development language, and allowing you to reason at the level of an object instance in your app, rather than rows, columns and joins. As you note, this really accelerates CRUD development tasks.

In theory, I think it is possible to represent every SQL Query to an ORM construct (assuming the ORM supports all the SQL constructs in the underlying database engine).

But you probably don't want to. If your application manages orders, having CRUD functionality from the ORM is really useful. But to write the report showing order values by sales person by month in a tabular layout would involve lots of ORM complexity, but could be represented in a fairly simple SQL Query. While the ORM may support every language construct from the underlying database engine, it probably doesn't make any promises about performance.